# Is CQL limiting Cassandra from being 'schema free'?

Tags: cassandra, database-schema, nosql

As I've understood it, one feature of Cassandra is that it's supposedly 'schema free', that is (coming from a RDBS perspective) a table could contain several rows with varying columns.

In fact I never found the word 'table' used in the official documentation, instead Cassandra was supposed to use SuperColumns and ColumnFamilies:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_family

But when reading up on **CQL**, the replacement language for SQL, creating these kinds of structures seems imposible, instead it closely mirrors a relation database structure that requires the creation and updating of tables and prohibiting on the fly attaching a new column to an row if it's not already defined in the table.

This is not at all what I need for my current project, as I need to store a lot of different information for each entity in the database (it's an experiment combining logic programming with probabilistic information and machine learning)

**I only just begun reading up CQL, Am I missing something or is Cassandra perhaps not the right choice for my project?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For documentation you will most likely find more up to date information at the Datastax Website as there is a paid documentation team constantly working  on Cassandra Docs.
[Datastax C* Docs](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/gettingStartedCassandraIntro.html)

The simplest solution for having arbitrary information in a row would be to use a MAP, LIST, or SET type in your logical row.

[CQL Datatypes Reference](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cql_data_types_c.html)

But if you want an arbitrary layout you can create a table in CQL like

```
CREATE TABLE entityvalue ( key blob, column_name blob, value blob , PRIMARY KEY (key, column_name))
```

and as a final option you could just use any of the old thrift drivers and have the old style if you like but there has been a vote to stop thrift development in Cassandra.

Comment: Thanks! I will look into all of those :)